# Regex pattern to format url

Tags: regex

I have this pattern `^(?:http://)?(?:www.)?(.*?)/?(.*?)$` but it's still not perfect. 
Let's say we have these urls to test against it:

```
example.com
example.com/
www.example.com/
http://example.com/
example.com/param
http://example.com/params/
```

The final output should be `example.com/` if there's no parameters and `example.com/params/` if with parameters. My problem is that it matches only second group. It doesn't look like `/?` is working otherwise it would stop on slash character. Is it possible to achieve what I want using only one pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the host name in $1?  Your regex is ambiguous, there are many ways to match it; the regex engine will prefer the longest, leftmost possible match.  If you don't want slashes in the first part, then say so. Explicitly. `(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?([^/]*)?/?(.*)?$`

Answer (score 0):

One that I've used is:

```
((?:(?:https?://)?[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+\-=&]+|www|ftp)\.[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+\-=&\.]+)
```

The problem with URLs is that there are SO many ways one can be written, which is why the above code looks so congested.  This will match all your examples above, but it will also match things like:

```
alkasi.jaias
```

Hopefully this will get you headed to where you need or want to go, and perhaps someone might be able to come up behind me and clean it up some (it's early morning, I'm getting ready for work, and am exhausted. :P)